# How can I print each letter twice on separate lines?

Tags: python

```
s = input('Enter some text: ')
doubled_s = '';
for c in s:
    doubled_s = doubled_s + c*2 + \n
```

Input:

```
testing
```

Expected output:

```
tt
ee
ss
tt
ii
nn
gg
```

I want each character to be doubled and the next character be doubled but printed on the next line.

Comment: What is the question? What is the problem?

Comment: `print(doubled_s)` in the end

Comment: you just need to `print(doubled_s)` after the loop

Comment: Put the newline in quotes: `\n` → `'\n'`.

Comment: you need two things: first add `print(doubled_s)` and change `n` to `"n"`

Comment: here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69605565/6194097) in a more pythonic way.

Answer (score 1):

Your code was almost correct:

```
s = input('Enter some text: ')
doubled_s = '';
for c in s:
    doubled_s = doubled_s + c*2 + '\n'  # missing quotes
print(doubled_s)                        # print final result
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not print directly in the loop ?

```
s = input('Enter some text: ')
for c in s: 
    print(c+c)
```

Comment: I have to say, it is not necessarily bad for once that a beginner doesn't put prints everywhere :p building a container is a good practice to learn

Comment: Agreed, I was aiming for simpler, not better :)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
doubles_s += c * 2 + '\n'
```

By doing so it will consider the next line syntax as string and adds to the double_s instead of treating it as object

Answer (score 0):

I respect @mozway answer and here it's in a more pythonic way.

```py
s = input('Enter some text: ')
doubled_s = ''
for c in s:
    doubled_s += c*2 + '\n'

print(doubled_s)
```

Comment: note that I only fixed the code trying to keep the changes minimal ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try printing directly inside loop, for next element, it'll directly print in next line, no need to put "\n". Your code:

```
s=input("Enter: ")
for c in s:
    print(2*c)
```